# Grails test-app is not executing all the tests

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spock

I have a simple application with some tests.
Actually, there is 1 JUnit test and some Specifications.
The thing is that when I run each of them separately they work fine.
But when I run:

```
grails test-app
```

It's not executing all the tests. All the tests are unit tests but they are in separate packages. But even into the package from the one it's executing, there is another test almost equal, but this one is not being executed as well...

Running `grails test-app -unit` I get the same problem.
Someone know if I need to do something else to be able to execute them all executing the `grails test-app` command?

Comment: grails test-app :unit is the right command. Each spock test should end with spec. No test class name should be same in any package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm my previous answer was deleted for some reason, but be sure that the Spock test ends with `Spec`, rather than `Test`.  If it ends with `Test`, then it will not be picked up.

e.g. `MyTest` -> `MySpec`